# How to read a looped string into another bigger string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read one array over and over into another bigger array/string. What have I done wrong? I get the error message `Thread1: signal SIGABRT`??

```
#include <stdio.h>
void make_nyckel(int size_krypto, char *nyckel);
int main()
{
    int size_krypto = 15;
    char nyckel[15];
    make_nyckel(size_krypto, nyckel);
    return 0;
}


void make_nyckel(int size_krypto, char *nyckel)
{
    char key[10] = { 'M', 'E', 'K', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'O', 'N', 'I', 'K' };
    char i, j;
    for (j = 0; j<size_krypto; j++)              
    {
        for (i = 0; i<9; i++)                  
        {
            *nyckel = key[i];                
            nyckel += 1;                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `*nyckel = key[i]; nyckel += 1;` This is done `9 * size_krypto` times.

Comment: You can't fit 90 characters (or whatever) in an array with space for `15` (14 if it's meant to be a string)

Comment: nyckel is only 15 char in size, you're writing 150 chars. You're exceeding the space allocated to you

Comment: Shouldn't you use the strncat function in the C standard library?

Comment: Ok I understand my faulty code. How would I solve this best? My goal is to have nyckel = MEKATRONIKMEKAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the first `for loop`, you can simply do with modulo operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void make_nyckel(int size_krypto, char *nyckel);
int main()
{
int size_krypto = 15;
char nyckel[16];
make_nyckel(size_krypto, nyckel);
printf("%s",nyckel);
return 0;
}


void make_nyckel(int size_krypto, char *nyckel)
{
char key[11] = { 'M', 'E', 'K', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'O', 'N', 'I', 'K' };
int i, j=0;
//   for (j = 0; j<2; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i<size_krypto; i++)
    {
        nyckel[j++] = key[i%10];


       // nyckel += 1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget the terminating NUL byte for `nyckel` if it's going to be used as a string!

```
void make_nyckel(int size_krypto, char *nyckel) {
    char key[] = { 'M', 'E', 'K', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'O', 'N', 'I', 'K' };
    size_t keylen = sizeof key; /* subtract 1 if key includes a '\0'
                                ** or use strlen(key) */

    for (size_t k = 0; k < size_krypto; k++) {
        nyckel[k] = key[k % keylen];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I simplify the question a bit. The real funktion is much bigger and complicated but builds the same way.. You made my day!